# python array dictionary inside dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, json, binance

I have python dictionary the code:

```
{'code': 200,
 'msg': '',
 'snapshotVos': [{'data': {'balances': [{'asset': 'ADD',
                                         'free': '10',
                                         'locked': '0'},
                                        {'asset': 'RDP',
                                         'free': '0',
                                         'locked': '0'},
                                        {'asset': 'SHIB',
                                         'free': '0',
                                         'locked': '947415'}],
                           'totalAsset': '152'},
                  'type': 'spot',
                  'updateTime': 1703807999000}]}
```

want to take the object values from 'balances'

I try code but just able to give the 'snapshotVos' and 'data'

I need result for all value in array 'balances'.

need keys from 'asset', 'free', 'locked'
and if any array has 0 in the 'free' and 'locked' remove this array.

```
print(repo['snapshotVos'])
rows = []
for re in repo['snapshotVos']:
    typeOrder = re['data']
    rows.append(typeOrder)
print(rows)
rows1 = []
for re1 in rows:
    typeOrder = re1['balances'][0]
    rows1.append(typeOrder)
print(rows1)
```

the result

```
>>> 200
>>> [{'type': 'spot', 'updateTime': 1703807999000, 'data': {'totalAssetOfBtc': '0.00021152', 'balances': [{'asset': 'ADD', 'free': '10', 'locked': '0'}, {'asset': 'ADXOLD', 'free': '0', 'locked': '0'}]}}]
>>> [{'totalAssetOfBtc': '0.00021152', 'balances': [{'asset': 'ADD', 'free': '10', 'locked': '0'}, {'asset': 'ADXOLD', 'free': '0', 'locked': '0'}]}]
>>>  [{'asset': 'ADD', 'free': '10', 'locked': '0'}]
```

Comment: If you want all elements in `balances`, loop over `re1['balances]` instead of just using `[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another nested loop:

```
for re in repo['snapshotVos']:
    for balance in re['data']['balances']:
        if not (balance['free'] == '0' and balance['locked'] == '0'):
            val = list(balance.values())
            if val not in rows1:
                rows1.append(val)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply it's work to remove any array has 0. `[{'asset': 'ADD', 'free': '10', 'locked': '0'}]` . but I want just a value not all array like: ADD, 10, 0

Comment: You mean `rows1.append(balance['asset'])`?

Comment: Please update the question to show the desired result.

Comment: yeah it good but just give me asset for each array `['ADD', 'ADXOLD']`. I want all data like that `[['ADD', '10', '0'], ['ADXOLD', '0', '1']]`

Comment: Then use `list(balance.values())`. This is all basic dictionary operations, you can learn it from any tutorial.

Comment: Can I remove code get array `['data']` in `rows = []` . and add all that is signal code as you write above. to keep the code small

Comment: Yes, you can put these loops inside the first loop, instead of creating the `rows` list. `for re in repo['snapshotVos']: for re1 in re['data']: ...`

Comment: can you pleas update that in the code above. and if the array is duplicate need to remove all duplicate and just keep one like that:  `[['ADD', '10', '0'], ['ADXOLD', '0', '1']][['ADD', '10', '0'], ['ADXOLD', '0', '1']]` . keep `[['ADD', '10', '0'], ['ADXOLD', '0', '1']]`

Comment: I've merged all the loops and added code to check for duplicates.

Comment: I add the code, in the line `val = list(balance.values())` give me error as message `Indent expected >>> val: list = list(balance.values())`

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks man, we find other error: `for balance in re1['balances']:`  `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'`

Comment: Sorry, I thought there was another level of lists.

Comment: okay thanks you for everything, have a nice day